# The difference between StreamReader.ReadLine and File.ReadLines?

Tags: c#, split

I tried to split the file about 1GB I do not know of any way to do this I use?
StreamReader.ReadLine or File.ReadLines?

**Note that I do not get all the data files in memory because it requires more memory.**

Comment: `StreamReader` is more flexible since it has other `Read...` methods. `ReadLines` only splits by lines. So I'd use `ReadLines` where possible and `StreamReader` if necessary,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`File.ReadLines` internally creates `ReadLinesIterator` which uses `StreamReader.ReadLine()` to read file line by line when you are enumerating lines:

```
internal class ReadLinesIterator : Iterator<string>
{
    private StreamReader _reader;

    public override bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (this._reader != null)
        {
            base.current = this._reader.ReadLine();
            if (base.current != null)
                return true;

            base.Dispose();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

So, difference is following - `StreamReader.ReadLine()` reads single line from stream. `File.ReadLines` iterates over all lines (until you stop) and uses `StreamReader.ReadLine()` for reading each single line from stream.

Answer (score -1):

ReadAllLines reads ALL the lines in the file in one go. StreamReaders ReadLine reads it line by line but you have to iterate through the file yourself until there is no more lines to read.
When you read something.. .of course its going to be in memory regardless.

Comment: Actually `File.ReadLines` have differed execution, and it will read only lines you need. You mixed it up with `File.ReadAllLines`

Comment: Good catch - my confusion was ReadLines and ReadAllLines