# Read text file when using a FileUpload control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to select a text file using a FileUpload control and read it into a string array.

I would like to understand if instead of using **StreamReader.ReadLine** I can use **File.ReadLines**.

I searched for some examples online but always find FileUpload control associated with StreamReader. I am missing the knowledge to understand why.

To complete the question: I am working on a web application. I am using StreamReader and it works fine but if I try to use `File.ReadLines(path)` where path is `FileUpload1.FileName` I cannot get the fullpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the difference between these two?

If not, please try to google and check. then you will find what you are looking for.

For you reference i am posting some links that will help you to understand it:

[Is StreamReader.Readline() really the fastest method to count lines in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243249/is-streamreader-readline-really-the-fastest-method-to-count-lines-in-a-file)

[The difference between StreamReader.ReadLine and File.ReadLines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287566/the-difference-between-streamreader-readline-and-file-readlines)

[File.ReadAllLines or Stream Reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989677/file-readalllines-or-stream-reader)

Comment: My question probably is less smarter than that. To use `File.ReadLines(fullpath)` I need the path of the file. How am I able to retrieve it using a FileUpload control?

Comment: @Endovelicvs: FileUpload must expose a property with the path of the selected file for upload. That is the path you can use for File.ReadLines

Comment: Path.GetFullPath((new Uri(absolute_path)).LocalPath);